# How to change the root password after memsql install?

Tags: singlestore

I've installed MemSQL community edition (single host cluster) and all is working well. I need to allow remote access to the database, but MemSQL installs the user root without a password. If I open up the 3306 port on the firewall, memSQL happily allows anyone to log in as root without a password.

I've tried to change the root user password via

```
mysqladmin -u root -h 127.0.0.1  password abc123
```

but I get the error of

```
mysqladmin: unable to change password; error: 'Unknown system variable 'password''
```

I also tried to change after connecting as root. all of these fail:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD = 'abc123';
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'PASSWORD'

mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('abc123');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('abc123')' at line 1

mysql> SET PASSWORD = OLD_PASSWORD('abc123');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('abc123')' at line 1
```

So I'm stuck.  The docs for MemSQL are pretty lightweight on this issue as well, and they don't seem to have a community page where I can ask about this.  I figure it's something really simple that I'm trying to do, not sure why it's so difficult, and for that matter, I'm not sure why MemSQL defaults to no security at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MemSQL to change a password of a user you should use the `GRANT` command:

```
grant all on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'password' with grant option;
grant all on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'password' with grant option;
```

Refer to the manual of the GRANT command and to a very detailed manual of configuring the cluster security:

http://docs.memsql.com/latest/ref/GRANT/

http://docs.memsql.com/latest/admin/security/#configuring-password-security

Comment: This answer *appears to work* but is not quite right. It only changes the password on the master aggregator for the cluster and this seems to isolate the master from the rest of cluster. According to the docs (http://docs.memsql.com/latest/admin/security/#configuring-password-security) you should use their CLI to change the password across the whole cluster with ` memsql-ops memsql-list -q | xargs -n 1 memsql-ops memsql-update-root-password --no-confirmation -p 'newpass'`

Answer (score 6):

In the June 2015 release of MemSQL Ops, you can now change the root password with one command using the `memsql-update-root-password` command. See these links for more information:

- http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/ops/cli/MEMSQL-UPDATE-ROOT-PASSWORD/
- http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/admin/security/#adding-or-updating-the-root-password

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please update you answer to work with the latest memsql?

Comment: This is the link for the updated one - https://docs.memsql.com/memsql-ops-cli-reference/v6.7/memsql-update-root-password/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mysql --user=root --password=abc123 --host=127.0.0.1
or
mysql -u root -p abc123 -h 127.0.0.1
```

Reference: [Mysql man page.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql)

You can change the root password with:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO "root"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Answer (score 0):

I observed one strange thing while changing password for root user in mysql as below.

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'mypassword'
```

Got  error as

```
mysqladmin: unknown variable 'database=mydatabase'
```

The reason for this is mydatabase variable has been set in the /etc/my.cnf file. I commented out that line, then everything works fine.

I though of sharing this in this thread.